# Fill invalid x,y position data from last valid row in Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Say I have a dataframe as follows:

```
time    id  x   y
0   1   23.1    12.7
0   2   12.2    32
0   3   232.2   76.3
1   1   -9999   -9999
1   2   98      55.7
1   3   67      54
2   1   56.8    56.8
2   2   99      -9999
2   3   443.4   34
```

Values in the x or y column equal to -9999 are invalid. I want to change this value to the value matching the row['id'] value for the previous ['time'] value. For instance, a row with invalid y value for id = 3 at time = 2 wants to replace the y value with id = 3 at time = 1.

This would become as follows:

```
time    id  x   y
0   1   23.1    12.7
0   2   12.2    32
0   3   232.2   76.3
1   1   23.1    12.7
1   2   98      55.7
1   3   67      54
2   1   56.8    56.8
2   2   99      55.7
2   3   443.4   34
```

How would I go about this (preferably without iteration)? I have looked at the ffill method, but I am unsure how to make that work while specifying it should be filled from the previous matching id number. I believe the first step would be fill the -9999 values to NA, but I am unsure how to proceed from there.

A couple of notes:

- The data is in time order
- There *may* be a different number of id values at each time step (so I could not just fill it with the row-3 value, for example)
- The id values may not be in any order within each time step

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If time values are consecutive you can replace `-9999` to missing values with forward filling misisng values per groups:

```
df[['x','y']] = df[['x','y']].replace(-9999, np.nan).groupby(df['id']).ffill()
print (df)
   time  id      x     y
0     0   1   23.1  12.7
1     0   2   12.2  32.0
2     0   3  232.2  76.3
3     1   1   23.1  12.7
4     1   2   98.0  55.7
5     1   3   67.0  54.0
6     2   1   56.8  56.8
7     2   2   99.0  55.7
8     2   3  443.4  34.0
```